# Flutter RenderFlex overflowed error on AlertDialog when keyboard appear

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have the following `AlertDialog` widget that behaves as following :
[image: Animated Image] 
and here is my code :

```
 showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(
              "Information sur le client $code",
            ),
            content: Container(
              height: mobileHeight * 0.75,
              width: mobileWidth * 0.9,
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.edit,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            size: mobileWidth * 0.05,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() => modifyNom = !modifyNom);
                            _textNameController.text = snapshot.data.nom;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      modifyNom
                          ? Flexible(
                              child: TextField(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: mobileWidth * 0.05,
                                ),
                                controller: _textNameController,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(),
                              ),
                            )
                          : Flexible(
                              child: Text(
                                '${snapshot.data.nom}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: mobileWidth * 0.05,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() => modifyContact = !modifyContact);
                            _textContactController.text = snapshot.data.contact;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Contact : ',
                      ),
                      modifyContact
                          ? Flexible(
                              child: TextField(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                controller: _textContactController,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(),
                              ),
                            )
                          : Flexible(
                              child: Text(
                                '${snapshot.data.contact}',
                              ),
                            ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Annuler"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(); // dismiss dialog
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
```

the issue is when i edit the `TextField` and the keyboard is shown i get this error :

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 211 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Column file:///C:/Users/asmou/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/Alerts/showAlertInfo.dart:49:28

The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
like a ListView.
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#a3d43 OVERFLOWING:
  needs compositing
  creator: Column ← FutureBuilder<Client> ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← DefaultTextStyle ← Padding ←
    Flexible ← Column ← IntrinsicWidth ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
    _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#50b4d ink renderer] ← ⋯
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=283.4, h=173.1)
  size: Size(283.4, 173.1)
  direction: vertical
  mainAxisAlignment: spaceBetween
  mainAxisSize: max
  crossAxisAlignment: center
  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap the Container Widget with ListView or SingleChildScrollView.

```
     showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(
              "Information sur le client $code",
            ),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
              height: mobileHeight * 0.75,
              width: mobileWidth * 0.9,
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.edit,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            size: mobileWidth * 0.05,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() => modifyNom = !modifyNom);
                            _textNameController.text = snapshot.data.nom;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      modifyNom
                          ? Flexible(
                              child: TextField(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: mobileWidth * 0.05,
                                ),
                                controller: _textNameController,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(),
                              ),
                            )
                          : Flexible(
                              child: Text(
                                '${snapshot.data.nom}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: mobileWidth * 0.05,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() => modifyContact = !modifyContact);
                            _textContactController.text = snapshot.data.contact;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Contact : ',
                      ),
                      modifyContact
                          ? Flexible(
                              child: TextField(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                controller: _textContactController,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(),
                              ),
                            )
                          : Flexible(
                              child: Text(
                                '${snapshot.data.contact}',
                              ),
                            ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
            actions: [
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Annuler"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(); // dismiss dialog
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

My whole scaffold body was a `Column` widget, and I had a similar render overflow error when using `AlertDialogs`;

Based on the flutter error message `...or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView` - I replaced `Column` for `ListView` and now I get no render overflow errors when using `AlertDialog`.

**Inside `build()`;**

```dart
return Scaffold(
      body: ListView( // formerly a Column()
        // your remaining UI
      ),
    ),
```